# TypeError: functionName is not a function but I've defined it as a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, mongoose, discord.js

Here is the error:

```
        logPunishment(target.id, logObj)
        ^

TypeError: logPunishment is not a function
```

Code:
bot/components/ban.js

```
const { logPunishment } = require('../db.js')
logPunishment(input1, input2)
```

some code of:
bot/db.js:

```
async function logPunishment(userId, punishmentObject){
    data = await User.findOne({id: userId})
    if (!data){
        await User.create({id: userId, punishments: []})
        data = await User.findOne({id: userId})   
    }
    punishments = data.punishments
    punishments.push(punishmentObject)
    User.updateOne({id: userId, punishments: punishments})
}


module.exports.logPunishment = logPunishment
```

logPunishment is clearly a function, but why does it say its not a function?
After console.log(logPunishment) this is the result:

```
undefined
```

why is that I couldn't understand. Please help!
What can I do to fix it now?
There are no other errors(for now) apart this
Please someone help!!!
I have tried this as per a answer

```
const logPunishment = require('../db.js').logPunishment,
```

which didn't work
Also I'm getting this warning after running the program:

```
(node:40712) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'logPunishment' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

I m not overiding any exports, I have confirmed it.

Comment: What else do you export from `db.js`? Could it be that you're overwriting the `exports` object with something else?

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue?

Comment: @Lennholm I m not overriding anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR it's because of your circular dependency. Consider the following two files in the same directory:

a.js

```
const { b } = require('./b');

module.exports.a = 'hello world';

console.log(b());
```

and b.js

```
const { a } = require('./a.js');
function b() {
    return a;
}

module.exports.b = b;
```

If you run `node a.js` you'll see the circular dependency error

> (node:9235) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'a' of module exports inside circular dependency

If you run `node b.js` you'll see

> TypeError: b is not a function

This has to do with how `require`s get resolved when there are circular dependencies. If you run `a` then it requires `b` which requires `a` which means `b` gets `a`'s *unfinished* exports, so you'll see `undefined` print instead of hello world. If you run `b` you'll get `b`'s unfinished exports in `a` which means that you'll be calling `undefined` as a function

You can fix it by moving the things that `b` requires from `a` into a different file: there's not really a good reason to use circular dependencies.